# how to supress popup window from emacs programatically?

Tags: emacs, popup, elisp

For example, I have this setup in my .emacs

```
(defun gtags-create-or-update ()
  "Create or update the gnu global tag file."
  (interactive)
  (if (y-or-n-p-with-timeout
       (format "Run gtags to create/update tag file for code at %s (default no)? "
               default-directory)
       5 nil) ; default - no run
      (unless (= 0 (call-process "global" nil nil nil " -p")) ; tagfile doesn't exist?
          (let ((olddir default-directory)
                (topdir (read-directory-name
                         "gtags: top of source tree: " default-directory)))
            (cd topdir)
            (shell-command "gtags -v")
            ;; (shell-command "gtags && echo 'created tagfile'")
            (cd olddir)) ; restore
        ;;  tagfile already exists; update it
        (shell-command "global -uv"))))
;; (shell-command "global -u && echo 'updated tagfile'")))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
  (lambda ()
    (require 'gtags)
    (gtags-mode t)
    (gtags-create-or-update)))
```

When I run `gtags-create-or-update` explicitly, emacs prompt in the minibuffer to ask me whether to create/update tag files. However, when I open a c/cpp file, it always pops up a GUI window ask me yes or no, which is super annoying. I am wondering why this is happening.

Comment: How are you opening your c/cpp files? When asking the user a question, Emacs generally uses a GUI window if the triggering action was initiated with the mouse, and the minibuffer if it was initiated by keyboard.

Comment: open files with `C-x C-f`, so it shouldn't use GUI window.

Comment: @phils: A small nitpick, it uses the echo area, not the minibuffer.

Comment: Daniel: right you are; `yes-or-no-p` uses the minibuffer, but `y-or-n-p` does not.

Answer (score 0):

What @phils says in the comment. To avoid dialog boxes in GUI Emacs, you can set the `use-dialog-box` to `nil` Put the line `(setq use-dialog-box nil)` in your initialization file.

Comment: thanks. but why no diaglog boxes when I run the command explicitly?

Comment: RNA: The real question is why *would* you get a dialogue window when initiating a command with the keyboard. I don't know the answer, but presumably there is something else in your config which is causing that non-standard behaviour.